# Start using Eclipse GIT with an existing project ... project files get moved

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control

Yesterday I wanted to start using Eclipse eGIT on an existing project following the instructions on http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html

This tutorial suggests to have the git repository outside of the workspace, and I followed this suggestion.

After the step "5.5. Using the Git Staging view for the initial commit" I committed my initial commit. Then I continued editing one of my source files that was still open. But when I tried to save my changes, Eclipse complained that the source file was no longer there.

Then I checked both my workspace and git folder, and the project files were only in git. This is mentioned nowhere in the tutorial. Is this normal behavior?

Even more surprising: In order to continue working normally with my already open files, I `copied` the project subfolder from .git back to the workspace folder. And now everything seems to be fine. My changes are reflected in workspace folder as well as in "Unstaged Changes" in the Git Staging view and in git folder.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Ok, I found out that the files really get moved. I needed to close all the open project files and then open them from package explorer again (which will open the files from git repository). This should be mentioned in the tutorial. I will open a topic on its Google group.

Comment: Please post this as an answer below so that other people can more easily see what actually happened, and so the question will no longer be marked "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that the files really get moved. I needed to close all the open project files and then open them from package explorer again (which will open the files from git repository).

Comment: how can i make git plugin to not move the files from my workspace to git folder